# Migrating data with Doctrine becomes slow

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I need to import data from one table in db A to another table in db B (same server) and I've chosen doctrine to import it.

I'm using a Symfony Commands and is all good for the first loop, just spends 0.04 secs, but then starts to become slower and slower and takes almost half an hour ...

I'm considering to build a shell script to call this Symfony command giving the offset ( I manually tried it and keeps same speed ). This is running in a docker service and the php service is around 100% CPU, however mysql service is 10%

Here part of the script:

```
class UserCommand extends Command
{
    ...
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $container = $this->getApplication()->getKernel()->getContainer();
        $this->doctrine = $container->get('doctrine');
        $this->em = $this->doctrine->getManager();
        $this->source = $this->doctrine->getConnection('source');

        $limit = self::SQL_LIMIT;
        $numRecords = 22690; // Hardcoded for debugging
        $loops = intval($numRecords / $limit);
        $numAccount = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $loops; $i++){

            $offset = self::SQL_LIMIT * $i;
            $users = $this->fetchSourceUsers($offset);

            foreach ($users as $user) {
                try{

                    $numAccount++;
                    $this->persistSourceUser($user);
                    if (0 === ($numAccount % self::FLUSH_FREQUENCY)) {
                        $this->flushEntities($output);
                    }

                } catch(\Exception $e) {
                    //
                }
            } 
        }
        $this->flushEntities($output);
    }

    private function fetchSourceUsers(int $offset = 0): array
    {
        $sql = <<<'SQL'
        SELECT email, password, first_name
        FROM source.users
        ORDER by id ASC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
SQL;

        $stmt = $this->source->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(1, self::SQL_LIMIT, ParameterType::INTEGER);
        $stmt->bindValue(2, $offset, ParameterType::INTEGER);
        $stmt->execute();
        $users = $stmt->fetchAll();

        return $users;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use limit / offset. Better use this kind of SQL "SELECT email, password, first_name FROM source.users where id > LAST_FOUND_ID limit LIMIT;". Offset gets slow with greater numbers and Primary key is automaticly indexed.

Comment: That maybe could help in mysql performance, but is all fine with that so far. The problem is the php service that takes all the cpu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the time it takes to `flush` is getting longer every other `flush` then you forgot to `clear` entity manager (which for batch jobs should happen after `flush`). Reason is that you keep accumulating entities in the entity manager and during every commit Doctrine is checking each and every one for changes (I assume you're using default change tracking).

> I need to import data from one table in db A to another table in db B (same server) and I've chosen doctrine to import it.

Unless you have some complex logic related to adding users (i.e. application events, something happening on the other side of the app, basically need some other PHP code to be executed) then you've chosen poorly - Doctrine is not designed for batch processing (although it can do just fine if you *really* know what you're doing). For "simple" migration the best choice would be to go with DBAL.

Comment: You were right, after clearing the entity manager after flush, I've speed up the process. Regarding the poor choice, you are actually right, I've have average doctrine skills and since I'm not that far in this script I will switch to DBAL with SQL scripts. Thanks for you help